# Storing lines from .txt FILE inside a Node. in C (Singly linked lists, FILES)

Tags: c, file, nodes

Let's say I have a line from .txt file that goes like
Tag: 131, Name: James, Surname: Musk, Age: 18
how can I loop through entire .txt file and make nodes from that info, storing only the values, 131,"James","Musk",18?

```
typedef struct Node {
    int age;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    int tag;
}Node;
```

I tried reading lines with while loop using f gets, then by using s scan f storing values inside variables and making nodes from that variables, but it didn't work, have no idea what to do next.

Code that I tried:

```
    void file_reading(FILE **account){`
    int tag;
    int balance;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    *account = fopen("account.txt","r");
    if(*account == NULL){exit(6); return;}

    char line[200];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),*account) != NULL){
        int num_chars_consumed = 0;
        if (sscanf(line, "Tag: %d, Name: %s, Surname: %s, Age: %d, Balance: %d%n", &tag, name, surname, &age, &balance, &num_chars_consumed) >= 5) {
            Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            new_node->tag = tag;
            strcpy(new_node->name, name);
            strcpy(new_node->surname, surname);
            new_node->age = age;
            new_node->balance = balance;
            insert_account(&root_of_tags, tag, balance, name, surname, age);
        }
        else {
            printf("Failed to read line: %s\n", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you've done in terms of code, so that'll be something to add for context.

Comment: looping thru the lines and reading them with `fgets` sounds like the right approach, post what you tried there and someone can probably help you.

Comment: @Jovan Dejanović Why does surname have the type char?

Comment: It didn't work. How the heck should we know what didn't work if you don't show your code?? Read this: [ask], then [edit] and clarify.

Comment: I suggest you use fgets() to read a line, the sscanf() to process that line. The format string `%[^;]` to read the tag name (`%*[^;]` if you don't care about the value and `[^,]` to read the value.  Maybe with space in those [], too.  Anyways, you need to do more work then just passing your task onto us.

Comment: The code you did write has 3 syntax errors.  Missing `;` after name and the `}`, and you are missing the identifier for the typedef (in addition to `surname` should be a string aka `char *` not just a `char`).

Comment: Break down the problem into parts. Trying building a list of nodes without reading from files. Then try reading from the file and print out the components you need. Put it all together when the parts work.

Comment: Passing in an `account` argument and then using it as if it were a local variable through assignment is really odd. If you're opening files, that's fine, but consider returning the handle if that's of any use after this function is complete, otherwise keep it entirely local.

Comment: `strcpy(new_node->name, name);` doesn't work because `new_node->name` hasn't been made to point at anything.

Comment: Because (e.g.) `new_node->name` is an _unitialized_ pointer, `strcpy(new_node->name, name);` --> `new_node->name = strdup(name);`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is with your format specifier in sscanf(). The following is what you have to read carefully:

Non-whitespace character, except format specifier (%): Any character that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and the function continues with the next character of format. If the character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving subsequent characters of the stream unread.

So, if your input line is "Tag: 131, Name: James, Surname: Musk, Age: 18", the name sscanf reads for you will be "James,", not "James" as you expected. Essentially, the comma will considered part of the name. Therefore, your sscanf function should be like this:

```
sscanf(line, "Tag: %d, Name: %s Surname: %s Age: %d%n", &tag, name, surname, &age, &num)
```

After the read, you will have to remove the comma from name and surname before you save them.

For those who are curious, here is a little program you can run and verify:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int tag, age, i, num;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];

    char *line = "Tag: 131, Name: James, Surname: Mask, Age: 18\n";

    i = sscanf(line, "Tag: %d, Name: %s Surname: %s Age: %d%n", &tag, name, surname, &age, &num);

    //name[strlen(name)-1] = 0;
    //surname[strlen(surname)-1] = 0;
    printf("[%d %d %s %s %d %d]\n", i, tag, name, surname, age, num);
    return 0;
}
```